# IBM Cloud Code Engine does not have authorization to pull an image from its own registry

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, container-registry, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I'm pretty new to IBM Cloud and Code Engine. I am trying to deploy an app called "project1" by uploading a docker container to IBM Cloud Container Registry and using it for a Code Engine application.

The problem is, the app creation always fails with this message (the namespace is project_namespace):

"Revision "project1-00001" failed with message: Unable to fetch image "icr.io/project1_namespace/project1": failed to resolve image to digest: GET https:/. See https://ibm.biz/BdPKqq; Authorization required. See [https://ibm.biz/BdPKqq."](https://ibm.biz/BdPKqq.%22)

or sometimes this message:

"Revision "project1-00001" failed with message: Unable to fetch image "icr.io/project1_namespace/project1": failed to resolve image to digest: GET https://icr.io/oauth/token?scope=repository%!A(MISSING)project1_namespace%!F(MISSING)project1%!A(MISSING)pull&service=registry: UNAUTHORIZED: Authorization required. See https://ibm.biz/BdPKqq; Authorization required. See [https://ibm.biz/BdPKqq."](https://ibm.biz/BdPKqq.%22)

I don't understand why authentication would be failing here. Here is what I do:

```
ibmcloud login
ibmcloud cr login

docker build -t $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME $DOCKERFILE_PATH 

ibmcloud target -g $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME
ibmcloud cr namespace-add $REGISTRY_NAMESPACE
ibmcloud ce project create --name project1
ibmcloud ce project select -n project1

docker tag $DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME icr.io/$REGISTRY_NAMESPACE/${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}:latest
docker push icr.io/$REGISTRY_NAMESPACE/${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}:latest

ibmcloud ce app create --name $CODE_ENGINE_APP_NAME --image icr.io/$REGISTRY_NAMESPACE/$DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME
```

Code Engine application should pull the icr.io image sucessfully. Right?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to create a `registry access secret` in your Code Engine project `project1`. Here are some of the useful links:

- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-add-registry#add-registry-access-ce
- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-deploy-app-private
- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-deploy-app-crimage

Answer (score 2):

IBM Cloud Code Engine needs access itself to the Container Registry, your namespace and the stored container images. In your commands, you showed that you login first (`cr login`), then access the container registry to add a namespace and push the image. It is your [private registry with the containers only visible to those with access](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-deploy-app-private).

Code Engine does not have any access to the Container Registry unless you grant it. That's, why you need to [create an access secret](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-add-registry#add-registry-access-ce).

Answer (score 0):

@Nayak was right. You need to create and link a secret to a private registry. Please note that, for instance, your container registry is hosted on Frankfurt then the Container Registry URL will be private.de.icr.io. Note the 'private' subdomain first.